# Named value tuples

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to use "var foo" but still having a named tuple?

```
(int first, int second) foo = "bar" switch
{
    _ => (0, 0)
};
```

Maybe some place where the switch itself can define the return type?

Comment: It is possible, but it will make your code longer than if you had used `(int first, int second) foo`. Are you sure you want to do this? What do you not like about `(int first, int second) foo`?

Comment: No, not urgent. It was a mixture of curiosity and a little benefit if this long definition was not at the beginning of the line. PS: and the question if this new C# 10 lambda return types can help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a cast before the `switch`:

```
var foo = ((int first, int second))("bar" switch
{
    _ => (0, 0)
});
```

Or you can cast each arm of the switch (you'd have to do this for each arm):

```
var foo = "bar" switch
{
    _ => ((int first, int second))(0, 0)
};
```

or specify the names of the tuple elements in each arm (again, you'd have to do this for each arm):

```
var foo = "bar" switch
{
    _ => (first: 0, second: 0)
};
```

But either way, this is longer than using `(int first, int second) foo`, so I don't recommend this.

Comment: OMG! I tried this cast and forgot the second braces.

Comment: As I just have one switch arm the third solution is exactly that I was looking for.